# Create a menu item and link it to a third-party url?

Tags: orchardcms

I want to add an item to the menu links and make it point to an external site. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean add a menu item on Your website? Use HTML is simple:
For example, your original site:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- head content here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just add a new 'li' in 'ul', make it like the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- head content here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      <!-- create other link from here -->
      <li><a href="http://sitename.com/">Other Site</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sorry, I didn't notice you are using OrchardCMS~ It's quite easy, just add new navigation as the document show:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Navigation-and-menus

Comment: Can I do this in the code? Show or not show menu items based on some criteria?